# Create a function to be called at an exact time each time an event has been created to a specific date in the calendar with ionic, php and my sql

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework

I have created a mobile application with ionic that is used to create sporting events among several participating users. When creating an event, the participating users are added and a date must be scheduled for the sporting event. These events are stored in the mysql database with their respective dates.

When it is the day of the event, I must send a notification to all the users who participate in said event.

**I already have the functions to create the notifications, I also have a function to list the events, their respective hours and send the notifications to the participants. The only thing I need is to know how I can make this function be called at an exact time each time an event has been created.**

What do you suggest to me to do this?

My backend is made with php. The databases are with mysql and firebase. I think that cronjobs do not work since they do not execute a specific date.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with cronjobs executing them through the database and doing a function that covers the difference in minutes. It works perfectly. Thank you very much